# React Native fixed footer doesn't stay on scroll

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

With this code:

```
<View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 20}}>
    <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
        <Text>Filler Text</Text>
    </ScrollView>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: "red"}}>
        <Text>Footer</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

it makes something like this:

[image]

which is exactly how I want it. However, if I add more filler text so that it takes up the whole screen, the footer goes down requiring me to scroll to get to it.

If anyone knows how to fix this, it would be really helpful. Thanks!

EDIT: this is react native, not plain HTML. position: fixed isnt supported unfortunately.

Comment: have you tried adding `position: fixed` so the element is positioned related to the browser window

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZsnuZ/ try this, throw in some lorem ipsum text to see it fixed on the bottom

Comment: position fixed isn't supported in react-native :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: "red", position: 'absolute', bottom:0}}>
        <Text>Footer</Text>
    </View>
```

Comment: Hi! For me, it still requires scrolling to see the footer (When I add filler content to the top).

Comment: Have you added position absolute and bottom 0 like I have typed?

Comment: Yes I have. Code looks like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/v3dfG7pz

Comment: Dear you have added two <View> which contains flex: 1

Comment: <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 20}}>
    <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
        <Text>Filler Text</Text>
    </ScrollView>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: "red", position: 'absolute', bottom:0}}>
        <Text>Footer</Text>
    </View>
</View>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "hack", you can try the following

```html
 {/* Where <View> is the container element */}

<View style={{flex: 1;}}>
  <AbsoluteElement style={{position:'absolute', right: 20, bottom:20}}></AbsoluteElement>
</View>
```

The container has been set to `flex: 1` which should take the full height of the parent.

If you need other elements in the view, e.g a `ScrollView`, then you can try:

```html
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <ScrollView>
    {/* Other Elements Can Go Here */}
  </ScrollView>

    {/* Other Elements Can Go Here */}
    
  <AbsoluteElement style={{position:'absolute', right: 20, bottom:20}}></AbsoluteElement>
</View>
```

Assuming the container element takes the full height of the page always with `flex:1`, the `<AbsoluteElement>` should always be fixed on the screen.

Answer (score -2):

```
.content {
    height: 10000px
}

.footer {
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
}    

<div class="content"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: react native doesnt support position: fixed unfortunately